# DynamoDb scan for nested attribute (.NET)

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

I've looked around the internet for an answer to this, but sadly to no avail, and the AWS Dynamo docs don't answer it either.

I have a dynamo db document structure like this :

```
{
    EmailAddress: test@test.com,
    Account: { 
                 AccountGuid: <guid>,
                 Roles: ["test", "test1"]
              }
}
```

I'm trying to get all email addresses and associated roles from the table where AccountGuid is a specific value.

I'm using the AWSSDK for .Net.

```
var result = Users.Scan(new ScanOperationConfig {
            FilterExpression = new Expression
            {
                ExpressionStatement = "Account.AccoundGuid = :guid",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, DynamoDBEntry>()
                {
                    {":guid", new Primitive(accountGuid.ToString())}
                }
            },
            AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "EmailAddress", "Account.Roles" },
            Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes,
            });
```

I can't get it to work, and I have no idea why. I've tried using ScanFilter also, but couldn't get that working either.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to address "AccountGuid" rather than "AccoundGuid" in the expression statement?

Comment: Sorry, just seen this. Yes, it was basically me being an idiot!